# Python For loop issue, able to fetch only the last iterated URL

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping

I have written this code to fetch image urls from a list of product urls (url_list)
and write them in a text file.
However the image urls of only the last product url gets saved. I think I have made some mistake in the for loop.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



File = open('urls_list.txt','r')
urls_list = File.readlines()




miniurl = 'http://www.jinliang.hk'



# opening a file in write mode

f = open("img.txt", "a")

for links in urls_list:
    print(links)
    # defining the html contents of a URL.
    grab = requests.get(links)

    # Defining the HTMLTableParser object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(grab.text, 'html.parser')
    for item in soup.find_all(attrs={'class':'detail_bottom'}):
        for link in item.find_all("span"):
            data = link.get('data-img')
            product_link = miniurl+data
            print(product_link)
            # traverse paragraphs from soup
            f.write(product_link)
            f.write("\t")
f.close()
```

Comment: share a sample of the urls_list.txt file

Comment: All of the lines read from your file, except possibly the very last one, will end with a newline character - making them an invalid URL.  Apply `.strip()` to each line to get rid of that character, and any other whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is not reading the input file. Its with output (for loop). I have given two urls in my input file. But only the last url is being passed in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

when you use **readlines()** it will read the last line only

you can do it in this way to read multi lines:

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'a') as f:
   for line in f.readlines():
      print(line)
```

this the mean idea and you can apply it in your code

good luck

Comment: Hi Hashem, thanks for the response. The problem is not reading the input file. Its with output (for loop).
I have given two urls in my input file. But only the last url is being passed in the loop.

Comment: Hi, in this way I suggest to make a business logic as a function, after that you can pass multi url and apply this function on urls, you can solve it using this code, but for good practice, make it in this way